# How do I add check boxes to users in permissions groups?

Tags: permissions

In my group permissions my predecessor removed the check box in front of the user's name.  I'm having to use SP Management Shell to remove users from groups.  How do I add the boxes back?[image]

[image: In a permissions group, when I select settings]

[image: Options when I select Group Settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before following these steps, ensure you have "Full control" on the site collection, it will avoid permission problems.

- Click on "Settings > List settings"
- On the settings page click the default view (usually "Detail View")
- Check "Selection Checkbox (checkboxes) "
- Click OK

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear.  This is for SharePoint 2010, for permissions, for the sites, subsites, pages, etc.

Comment: hello, this solution is for SharePoint 2010. I have the same display as the image in your post so I thought it should work if you start by clicking on settings button of the permission list and follow my instructions.  (Another possibility is that the checkbox is hidden using custom javascript or css but I don't think someone would do that :) )

Comment: I've added a couple images.  When I go into the permissions group "IT Managers" and select settings at the top, then Group settings, this is what I get.  There is no option for Selection Checkbox.  thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. I see you clicked on "Settings > Group Settings".  You should click on "Settings > List Settings". It should be the fourth link on the "Settings" button. Do you have it ?

Comment: No, there is only Group Settings (see 2nd photo).

Comment: Hello, the second photo is cut so I can see only "Groups Settings" and "View Group permissions". I have 4 links in my environment.  By the way do you have "Full Control" permission on the site collection ?  If you are not sure, can you use the "system account" ?

Comment: My name wasn't listed as a site administrator.  My group was, but my name wasn't specifically.  I've added it, and now I can see the List Settings option you have been talking about.  However, I don't see "Detail View" or "Selection Checkbox (checkboxes)." :( Thanks.

Comment: "List View" had a checkbox under Default View, so I opened that view and found the "Selection Checkbox (checkboxes)" option.  I selected that and it added it to all of my permissions groups.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I am glad you could solve your problem !

Comment: I changed my answer so it is more accurate. Please, if this helped you, can you set it as answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my permissions groups were missing checkboxes next to the group members:

So, in order to remove a user from the group, I would have to do it through Powershell.  However, there’s an easier way; add the checkboxes back to the permission groups.

**To do this, first you have to make sure that you are a Site Collection Administrator:**

1)From the home page of your farm, select Site Actions, then Site Settings.

2)Under Users and Permissions, select “Site collection administrators.”

3)If your name is not in this box, add it.  Select OK.

**Next, you need to modify the List Settings for the default view of site permissions groups:**

4)Select Site Actions from the top left corner of your screen, then Site Permissions.

5)Locate a Permissions group, such as ‘Human Resources Visitors.’

6)Select the dropdown for Setting, then List Settings.

[image: 6]

7)Scroll down to the Views section and select the View that has a checkmark under “Default View” next to it.

[image: 7]

8)Place a check in the box for “Selection Checkbox (checkboxes)”, and change the Position from Left to “2.”  This will make the checkbox appear next to the users name in the permission group.

[image: 8]

9)Select OK.

10)Return to your permissions group and notice that there is now a checkbox next to each name.

[image: 10]